# Mysql query latest entry with multiple group by

Tags: mysql

right now I'm using the following simple query which shows the history of  training progress per user:

```
SELECT user_id, date, project, status
FROM a_training_status
GROUP by user_id, project
```

This way I can see when people completed their training and when status has changed.
But I would also need a table which shows only the lastest status per rater and project.
I tried with select max(date) but the status column does not match.

Is there a way to have two group by and only show the latest?

Comment: Can you show table design

Comment: Can you provide a sample data? And from that sample what would be the desired result from it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id, project, status
FROM a_training_status AS t1
WEHRE `date` = (SELECT MAX(`date`) 
                FROM a_training_status AS t2
                WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.project = t2.project)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL `MAX`

```
SELECT *
FROM a_training_status t1
Where date=(SELECT MAX(t2.date)
              FROM a_training_status t2
              WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.project = t2.project)
```